# How to turn off Mac's sounds by default?

Tags: macos, audio

In some situations I would open my macbook in a public place or library, and I still have something open that produces sound, such as music or a chat program giving notifications. I would like to have my sound be muted by default when I open the lid. Anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Control Plane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) is ideal for this sort contextual computing. It's a free, open source app in which you can configure a context. For example a context 'library'. In that context certain rules apply (i.e. mute device). The context can be automatically triggered by numerous things (i.e. sleep/wake event, connected wifi, running applications, ...)

It is useful in many other situations as well, I use this app extensively.

Here is how you can configure Control Plane to do what you asked for:

1. Create a new context and give it an appropriate name (i.e. *muted*)
   [image: Contexts view in Control Plane]
2. Under *Evidence Sources* make sure *Sleep/Wake Event* is checked

[image: List of evidence sources in Control Plane]

3. Under *Rules* add a new *Sleep/Wake Event Rule* and set it so when system goes to sleep it activates the *muted* context with the confidence slider set to 100%.

[image: New Sleep/Wake Event rule]

4. Under *Actions* add a *Mute* action (*Sound and Music Actions > Mute*). Set it so that system is muted on arrival at context *muted*.

[image: New Mute action in Control Plane]

There you go. You could of course make the context switch to *Muted* more intelligent by using and combining different rules (each with its own confidence level).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried muting the sound?

[image]

Muting the sound before closing the lid and/or rebooting will keep the sound muted.

I also found this: [Mute volume of macbook on sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/113437/122959)

Comment: I want my sound to be automatically muted. I know how to mute the sound in general.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer with a link to something similar.

Comment: Thanks, maybe this is too much a duplicate?