# Muting Mac on Sleep/Wake?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, audio, sleep-wake

I would like my Mac to mute every time it wakes from sleep to avoid unintentionally playing loud music/videos when I'm at a meeting.

I found this related question: 
[Mute volume of macbook on sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/113288/371576)

but the answer may be outdated, and I can't comment because my reputation isn't high enough. Does anyone have an updated fix?

Here is what I did:

I installed [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/), ran the script, then the following code:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share/man/man8 
$ sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2.1/sleepwatcher /usr/local/sbin 
$ sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2.1/sleepwatcher.8 /usr/local/share/man/man8
```

Then, per the answer to the previous question, I did:

```
$ /usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --sleep /usr/bin/osascript -e 'set volume with output muted'
```

I get the following error:

> sleepwatcher: invalid option -- e

If I remove `e`, it says

> sleepwatcher: superfluous arguments ignored: "set volume with output muted ..."

Answer (score 1):

Sleepwatcher only accepts a single executable/script, so you have to put the command you want to run in its own file.

Create a file `mute.applescript`:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
set volume with output muted
```

Set it as executable:

```
chmod +x mute.applescript
```

Then do:

```
/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --sleep /path/to/mute.applescript
```

Comment: I'll tell you exactly what I did: 1) open TextEdit 2) paste `#!/usr/bin/osascript set volume with output muted` 3) save file as `mute.applescript` to Desktop 4) close TextEdit, open Terminal 5) `cd Desktop` on terminal 6) `chmod +x mute.applescript` 7) `/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --sleep mute.applescript` 8) terminal freezes. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Does it show "Not Responding"?

Comment: no, it just goes to a blank newline after I hit enter. it says `Desktop -- sleepwatcher -- verbose --sleep mute.applescript` on the terminal window

Comment: @Sas that's exactly what it's supposed to do (like all CLI programs). If you want it to run in the background, use a LaunchDaemon.